# Multicast Delegation in Typhoon

Tags: typhoon

I'm using multicast delegation in my project and I'd like to integrate it with typhoon as it is using standard one-to-one objective-c delegates.

As for multicast delegation, I'm using NSProxy approach, explained here: http://arielelkin.github.io/articles/objective-c-multicast-delegate/.

My code so far:

```
   -(AViewController*)aViewController{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition
     *definition) {  
         }];
   }

     -(BViewController*)bViewController{  
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[BViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition
     *definition) {
         }];
   }

     -(AppController*)appController{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AppController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition
     *definition) {
    [definition setScope:TyphoonScopeSingleton];
    [definition injectProperty:@selector(delegate) with:[self appControllerMulticastDelegate]];
         }];
    }

     -(MulticastDelegate*)appControllerMulticastDelegate{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[MulticastDelegate class]
     configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
    [definition setScope:TyphoonScopeSingleton];
         }];
     }
```

Is it possible to inject aViewController and bViewController into appControllerMulticastDelegation? How should I solve this issue? I think that I should use method injection (for addDelegate: method in MulticastDelegate), but have no idea how to do it...

**EDIT**
Just asking. Would it be possible to inject instance from current definition (non-singleton - TyphoonScopeObjectGraph) to some other definition, something like this (method injection):

```
-(AViewController*)aViewController{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[AViewController class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition
     *definition) { 
    [(TyphoonDefinition*)[self appContollerMulticastDelegate] injectMethod:@selector(addDelegate:) 
            parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *method) {
            [method injectParameterWith:/*instance of AViewController that will be created*/];
        }];
}
```

*On runtime*: AViewController* aViewController = [(MyAssembly*)factory aViewController];// creates a new unique instance of AViewController and adds it to appContollerMulticastDelegate subscribers;

Answer (score 1):

Since your view controllers have the TyphoonScopeObjectGraph its necessary to:

- Register with the Multicast delegate on creation
- Detach before destroying.

Unfortunately its not really possible to wire this up using Typhoon, so you'd have to simply do it in your view controller.

The registration part could be done:

- Add [a new property of type MulticastDelegate to UIViewController](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/)

Add category methods:

```
- (void)registerWithDelegate
{
    self.delegate addSubscriber:self];
}
```

Then when registering your view controller:

```
- (BViewController *)bViewController
{
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[BViewController class] 
        configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition)
    {
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(delegate) with:[self appControllerMulticastDelegate]];
        definition.beforeInjections = @selector(registerWithDelegate);
    }];
}
```

But unfortunately Typhoon does not have any hooks into the dealloc of a component.

Instead simply:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_delegate removeSubscruber:self];
}
```

**Possible Useful Feature:**

Here's something that Typhoon doesn't do, but it would be a potentially interesting feature: Define before/after injection callbacks with arguments, such as:

```
[definition invokeBeforeInjection:@selector(registerWithDelegate:) 
    parameters:^(TyphoonMethod *method) 
{ 
    [method injectParameterWith:[self multicastDelegate];
}
```

By the way, is there a reason you prefer hand-rolled multicast delegates over Apple's NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: It doesn't work in my case. View controller is created only if needed (TyphoonScopeObjectGraph), but controller is created on app launch (TyphoonSingletonScope). When app creates a view controller before a presentation (i.e. [[TyphoonComponentFactory defaultFactory] componentForKey:@"aViewController"]), a new object is not injected to multicast delegate (addDelegate: is not called).

How should I cope with this? Do I use DI in a wrong way?

Comment: You should not use defaultFactory.componentForKey but: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Obtaining-Built-Components#proceeding-from-one-object-graph-to-another

Comment: As for the scopes, yes if your ViewControllers are not singletons, then you will need register them with the Mutlicast on creation, and detach before destroying.

Comment: https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/264
https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/issues/265

Comment: As for detaching delegates before destroying, it's not an issue in that case. [NSHashTable weakObjectsHashTable]; works like an array of weak references - no need to detach delegates manually.

Comment: @squikend (y) In that case you should be able to use the above solution . . meanwhile, we'd be interested if you had any comments on the linked GitHub issues above.

Comment: Please, have a look on edited question. Is this solution possible in Typhoon?

Comment: No its not. The answer above is the closest possible solution that meets the goal: a) Register an instance with a delegate on creation b) Declare all the wiring in TyphoonAssembly . . I've suggested an improvement, and opened a ticket for that (see comment above). . we can explore alternative approaches on that ticket. Perhaps a block. `^(id newInstance, MyAssembly *assembly) { //do something}`